# How can I store SGD delta package with bitbucket pipeline

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, sfdx-error

I'm using SGD for my salesforce deployment using Bitbucket pipeline.
sfdx sgd:source:delta --to HEAD --from HEAD^

It is working however I want to store/see content(package) of metadata to be deployed.
Can someone help me understand if there is a way to store the differences, If yes where can it be stored?

I got below from https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta but not sure how/where to introduce this change, I tried updating commands on bitbucket-pipeline.yml file but it got failed with below error

```
mkdir changed-sources

sfdx sgd:source:delta --to "HEAD" --from "HEAD~1" --output changed-sources/ --generate-delta
```

Error:

```
ERROR running force:source:deploy:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'package/package.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a bit late but a simple **cat** should do the trick:

```
cat package/package.xml
```

Include it in your script after you call *sfdx sgd:source:delta* and it should print the contents of the generated file into console